# XSD equivalent for its respective XML file

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to define certain parameters in xml file as key value pairs. Also, I want to create XSD file with respect to my XML file.
Please refer below.

My XML File:

```
<all_configurqations>
    <database>
            
        <ids>
            <item key="1"  value="10" />
            <item key="2" value="20" />
        </ids>
        
        <port></port>
        
        <users>
            <item key="a"  value="aa" />
            <item key="b"  value="bb" />
        </users>
        
        <pass>
            <item key="a"  value="aaa" />
            <item key="b"  value="bbb" />
        </pass>     
    
    </database>     
</all_configurqations>
```

My XSD File :

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="all_configurqations">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="database">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              
              <xs:element name="ids">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="id" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element> 
              
              <xs:element type="xs:int" name="port"/>
               
               <xs:element name="users">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="user" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              
              <xs:element name="pass">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="password" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

What should be the way to define key value pair in XSD file. Is key value pair defination correct in my XML file?

Comment: Your XSD comes nowhere close to describing your XML instance; it's so far off that this is essentially a "please write the code for me" question. I suggest you start by finding a tool that generates an XSD from an instance document (there are plenty available), then study the output, read enough about XSD to understand it, and then edit/refine it as appropriate to define the constraints you want to enforce. (An XSD generated from a single instance document won't usually describe exactly the constraints that you want to apply to all documents of the same "kind".)

Answer (score 1):

After creating your xml got to link : https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-xml-to-xsd-converter
and paste your xml, you will  get XSD.